# Exercise 3.4.7 from Tao Analysis I (Set of all partial functions)

Tags: functions, set-theory, solution-verification

This is an exercise you can find [here](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ecTsDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA61&lpg=PA61&dq=tao%20analysis%20exercise%203.4.7&source=bl&ots=apH8JZkSMx&sig=ACfU3U0LBch9IdFzljUomzgyGNUqmcxsvQ&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiyqJzqpZXqAhUS5uAKHbgzBsMQ6AEwAXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=tao%20analysis%20exercise%203.4.7&f=false), but I recall the context:

> Let $X, Y$ be sets. Define a *partial function* from $X$ to $Y$ to be
> any function $f: X' \rightarrow Y'$ with $X' \subseteq X$ and $Y'\subseteq Y$.
> Show that the collection of all partial functions from
> $X$ to $Y$ is itself a set.

Tao's hint is to use the following four results from set theory exposed in his textbook:

> 1. Lemma 3.4.9. Let $X$ be a set. Then there exists a set $\{Y \, : \, Y \text{ is a subset of } X\}$. It is denoted $2^X$.
> 2. Axiom 3.10. Power set axiom: let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. Then there exists a set, denoted $Y^X$,  which consists of all the functions from $X$ to $Y$.
> 3. Axiom 3.6. Replacement axiom.
> 4. Axiom 3.11. Union axiom: let $A$ be a set, whose all elements are themselves sets. Then there exists a set $\bigcup A$ whose elements are those objects which are elements of elements of $A$, i.e., $x \in \bigcup A$ iff $x \in S$ for some $S \in A$.
>    A consequence: if one has some set $I$, and for each element $\alpha \in I$ we have one set $A_\alpha$, then we can form the union set $\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} A_\alpha$ by defining: $\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} A_\alpha := \bigcup \{ A_\alpha \, | \, \alpha \in I\}$.

There are some very complete solutions out there, e.g. [here](https://taoanalysis.wordpress.com/2020/06/19/exercise-3-4-7/). My sketch of proof is much shorter, thus I think that there are many errors in it. Here it is:

- Let be $X' \subseteq X$ and $Y' \subseteq Y$. If both $X'$ and $Y'$ are fixed, then per the power set axiom (3.10), there exists a set $Y'^{X'}$ which consists of all the functions from $X'$ to $Y'$.
- By lemma 3.4.9, there exist a set $2^X$ which consists of all the subsets of $X$, and a set $2^Y$ which consists of all the subsets of $Y$.
- Now we *fix* an element $X'$ of $2^X$. Let be $Y'$ an element of the set $2^Y$, $f$ a function, and $P$ the property ``$P(Y', f)$: $f$ is a function from $X'$ to $Y'$''. Per the replacement axiom, there exists a set $\{f \, | \, P(Y', f) \text{ is true for some } Y' \in 2^Y\} = \{f \, | \, f: X' \rightarrow Y' \text{ for some } Y' \in 2^Y\}$. This set is related to a *fixed* subset $X' \subseteq X$, so let's denote this set $S_{X'} = \{f \, | \, f: X' \rightarrow Y' \text{ for some } Y' \in 2^Y\}$.
- Now we apply the union set (3.11), especially in its second formulation. If we denote $I = 2^X$, then for each element $X' \in I$ we do have one set $S_{X'}$, which is defined above. Thus, there exists a set $\bigcup_{X' \in 2^X} S_{X'} := \bigcup \{S_{X'} \, | \, X' \in 2^X\}$. And, for every function $f$, we have $f \in \bigcup \{S_{X'} \, | \, X' \in 2^X\}$ iff there exists $X' \in 2^X$ such that $f \in S_{X'}$, i.e. if there exists $X' \subset X$ and $Y' \subset Y$ such that $f: X' \rightarrow Y'$.
- Consequently, we have proved that there exists a set which consists of the collection of all partial functions from $X$ to $Y$.

What does make this proof incomplete and/or incorrect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key observation is that this set is equal to
$$\bigcup \{Y'^{X'}: (X', Y') \in 2^X \times 2^Y\}$$
so you can use union axiom if you have shown that
$$\{Y'^{X'}: (X',Y')\in 2^X \times 2^Y\}$$
is a set. That this is actually a set follows by replacement applied to the set $2^X \times 2^Y$, in which we use power set axiom and pairing axiom.

Comment: This is indeed a way to solve it! But this exercise appears (in Tao's book) before the introduction of Cartesian products, so I suppose that Tao expects the reader to solve this exercise without this notion. (And that makes this exercise slightly harder, probably.)

Comment: You don't really need cartesian products. You can probably do something where you take two nested unions.

Comment: @ε-δ, can you please clarify more how to get around the Cartesian product in your solution. I was able to solve this only using Cartesian product which is not yet introduced at this point in the book.